# failed to start glassfish 4 plugin in eclipse luna using java 8

Tags: java, eclipse-plugin, glassfish-4, eclipse-luna

The Glassfish plugin cant start in eclipse luna using java 8 .Withount any exception in glassfish log file it will be time out and i get "Unable to start server on time.
java.util.concurrent.TimeoutException".

Answer (score 1):

I got the answer, i changed host name from `localhost` to real numeric IP (`127.0.0.1`) and then GlassFish started.

Comment: which file do you have modified for that?

Comment: @dev could you please elaborate. Like what numeric ip did you used. Your system ip?

Answer (score 0):

Is your Server started already? If not, you can modify your Timeout-Value for startup and shutdown in Eclipse Server View (Timeouts).

Comment: I did it , but still the server can not start

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue. I think he meant in the server tab of Eclipse, create a new instance of a server and change the "Server's host name:" from "localhost" to "127.0.0.1".

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. I did the following to fix:

1. delete the server
2. create a new server
3. when asking for "Server's host name", using "127.0.0.1" instead of "localhost" (same as the answer of Clueless)
4. start the server. This time it worked.
5. delete the server again
6. create a new server and use "localhost" for "Server's host name".